# Can I use showPythonShell for Django debugging?

Tags: python, django, debugging

I really like Python because I can use its shell to explore things.

Is it possible to do the same while developing a django app?

I mean, is it possible to do:

```
def process_request(request):
    ...
    if(request.FILES != none):
        __builtins__.debug_request = request
        showPythonShell();
    ...
```

so I can experiment with the request?

Thanks :D

Comment: something like: manage.py shell?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/#module-django.test.client

Comment: @monkut well, yes!!! but I also want to receive ACTUAL http request from the client, and then exit to a python shell so that I can explore about the request.

Comment: Are you looking for breakpoints (http://v3.mike.tig.as/blog/2010/09/14/pdb/)?

Comment: @user269334 ... so did the answers solve your problem then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `ipython` and substitute `showPythonShell()` with:

```
from IPython import embed; embed();
```

This will do exactly what you are expecting i.e. launch an `ipython` shell from within your if statement. The benefits of having an `ipython` shell are tab completion, magic functions etc. as reviewed [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/tutorial.html). I've been developing in python for quite some time now and this is primarily the method I use to debug anything, including django.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the python debugger: [`pdb`](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html)

Or even better [`ipdb`](http://www.djm.org.uk/enhance-pdb-debugging-ipdb-ipython/), which gives you *tab completion*, *syntax highlighting* and other [`IPython`](http://ipython.org/) features.

```
if(request.FILES != none):
    import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

As soon as the line is reached you are dropped to a debugging shell where you can examine the request. Check the pdb docs for all [available commands](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands).

Here is a really good blog post explaining all the details: http://aymanh.com/python-debugging-techniques